# c++ array wont show correct value

Tags: c++, arrays

Alright so Im having a problem creathing this simple programand i have no whats malfunctioning.

I have to create a program that takes all the positive elements from one array and puts them in a new one. The positive elements from the first array do show up in the second but all of them are displayed as -858993460. I have no idea whats causing the problem but i think everything theoreticly checks out because the counter definetly works.

Heres the code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int i, n, j = 0, a[25], b[25];
    printf("Input the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Imput the elements\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d-i element: ", i); scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        if (a[i]>0) {
            a[i] = b[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("The array with positive elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", b[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your post and paste the code in your post.  Convert tabs to spaces before posting.

Comment: Have a look at [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line was failing (highlight with comments)?

Comment: http://http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/

Comment: @OP: I know you're new here. Next time, remember to post your code here instead of a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you never assign values to array `b`.

Change

```
a[i]=b[j];
```

to

```
b[j]=a[i]; // assign values here
```

Comment: it should be `b[j]=a[i]`

Comment: @rockoder Fixed. Wrote it too fast. :P

Answer (score 0):

The array `b` has not been set with valid values before this:

```
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
         if (a[i]>0) {a[i]=b[j];
         j=j+1;
 }
```

The `a` slots may be assigned garbage.